Kubernetes Dot net core
 "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": "Error",
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
              "connectionString": "data source=xxx;initial catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;persist security info=False;TrustServerCertificate=xxx;packet size=4096;max pool size=1000;",
              "tableName": "xxx",
              "autoCreateSqlTable": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }

I have to use this in kubernetes as config map as key value pair
 Serilog__MinimumLevel: "Error"
 Serilog__WriteTo__0__Args__autoCreateSqlTable: "FALSE"
 Serilog__WriteTo__0__Args__tableName: "xxx"
 Serilog__WriteTo__0__Name: "xxx"

When I have used these keys using this key value pair.
Getting issue Name is not defined whenever I am supplying these values from configmap. otherwise without these keys no issue in deployment.  I am supplying other key also from config map then there is no error.
how can we make these keys to be read from configmap. or am I using wrong syntax while supplying these keys.
